# Don't Show a field drf serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

Is there a way so that a field of serializer doesn't show in response?
I know this way:

```py
extra_kwargs = {
  "field_name": {"write_only": True},
}
```

But problem is someone may change this field with a PUT request.
Can we don't show a field and don't accept changing it?
########
Example:
let's assume we have the following serializer:

```
class RandomSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    other = otherSerializer(write_only=True)
    a = serializers.charField(max_length=100, source="other.a")
    class Meta:
        model = Random
        fields = ['other', 'a', ...]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "other": {"write_only": True},
        }
```

Problem of this approach is someone can provide "other" in request and that's not i want.
In other words I would like to make a field both write_only and read_only

Comment: *"I would like to make a field both write_only and read_only"* How does that make sense?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I guess it's something like `get_or_create`, where we retrieve object if it doesn't exists or create a new one.

Comment: Can you show your view that is using this serializer?

Comment: I mean that field is used to generate other fields out of it
for example other.a,
and a is showed in response
but "other" must not be shown